# Found my wallet on my external HDD but it has changed the adress and it was empty after synchronising. I can see in blockchain.info that its not empty

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery

Can anyone help me,i found my wallet from 2013 on my HDD. I noticed that it has changed its adress and there were no BTC on it after synchronising on my laptop. I can see in blockchain.info.com that its not empty.

Comment: What kind of wallet is it (what software)? What do you mean by changed its address? What do you mean by synchronizing? What did you get from the wallet that you input to blockchain.info?

Comment: Its the bitcoin core qt wallet. It has to be synchronised to send and receiver btc. I had it for 4 years on my external HDD, however wen i
transferred the wallet to my laptop i noticed that the amount of bitcoin was zero and the adres had changed. I checked the old adress on blockchain.info.com and the amount of btc never changed since 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core does not have "the address". There is no "the address" in a wallet. Wallets have more than one address, and every time you want to receive Bitcoin, it will give you a new address. This does not mean that old addresses are forgotten or deleted. They are still there and the wallet still knows about them.

You will not be able to see your balance without syncing the entire blockchain. If the version of Bitcoin Core you have is old, I highly suggest that you install the latest version of Bitcoin Core and let it sync from scratch. To do this, download and install Bitcoin Core 0.15.1 and then delete everything in the data directory **except for the wallet.dat file.** Then start Bitcoin Core and let it fully sync.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try it, if it not work i hope you can help me further ;-)

Comment: Hi Andrew, i synchronized the newest version of Bitcoin core, can you please explain me step by step what to do and how so that i don't ruin it.

Comment: Do you see your Bitcoin? Is the correct wallet.dat file in the data directory?

Comment: No i dont see the amount of BTC, i don't know but i can see that the receive adress is wrong.
If the wallet.dat file is wrong how can i import the right one?

Comment: Stop Bitcoin Core. Go to the Bitcoin Core data directory. Move the wallet.dat file in there to a safe location. Copy your original wallet.dat file (the one that you want to use) into the data directory. Start Bitcoin Core again.

Comment: I think thats the problem, i don't have a wallet.dat file. I store my BTC core wallet in 2013 on my external HDD and never thought about it till now 2017.

Comment: Then your wallet.dat file is on the external hard drive. Bitcoin Core's wallet will not function without a wallet.dat file. Either you provide one or it makes one. If it makes one, it will not be the one that you want to use.